How to adjust a point in proj?
proj_geod returns a PJ_GEOD (geodesic), which contains the distance, the forward az, and the reverse az between two ordered PJ_COORD under ellipsoid projections such as EPSG:4979.
I want to adjust (or create) a PJ_COORD at some fraction along the PJ_GEOD from the first point.
I am using proj.9.4 (stable) and C++20
Any clues?
#include <iostream>
#include "proj.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    constexpr double DEG_TO_RAD = .017453292519943296;
    auto ctx = proj_context_create();
    PJ* obj = proj_create(ctx, "EPSG:4979"); //WGS84
    PJ_COORD pt_a({24.94583 * DEG_TO_RAD, 60.192059 * DEG_TO_RAD, 0.0, HUGE_VAL});  //long/lat Helsinki.
    PJ_COORD pt_b({2.352222 * DEG_TO_RAD, 48.856667 * DEG_TO_RAD, 0.0, HUGE_VAL});  //long/lat Paris.
    PJ_GEOD helsink_paris = proj_geod(obj, pt_a, pt_b).geod;
    std::cout << "From Helsinki it is " << std::format("{:.2f}", helsink_paris.s/1000)  << "km to Paris, bearing: " << helsink_paris.a1 << std::endl;
//  Using proj, how do I create a PJ_COORD which marks the first kilometer of my journey?

}

>>From Helsinki it is 1914.57km to Paris, bearing: -121.079

I am aware that the command line geod application supports exactly this function, and that there's an example of it doing that in the documentation.

proj appears to be using code directly linked to Karney's GeographicLib when it comes to geodesic functions, and their geod application calls some functions directly from it, so I can use that.
It doesn't directly answer the question - but it does solve the need.
#include <iostream>
#include <GeographicLib/Intersect.hpp>

using namespace GeographicLib;
//
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const Geodesic& wgs84 = Geodesic::WGS84();
    double lat1 = 60.192059, lon1 = 24.94583;  // Helsinki
    double lat2 = 48.856667, lon2 = 2.352222;  // Paris
    double r_fwd_azi,r_distance,r_rev_azi;
    wgs84.Inverse(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, r_distance, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
    std::cout << "From Helsinki it is " << std::format("{:.2f}", r_distance/1000) << "km to Paris, bearing: " << r_fwd_azi << std::endl;
    GeodesicLine h_p = wgs84.Line(lat1, lon1, r_fwd_azi);
    double lat3, lon3;  //position on journey to paris.
    h_p.Position(1000000, lat3, lon3); // 1000km in m.
    std::cout << "From Helsinki, 1000km to Paris takes us to Våbensted: " << lat3 << "," << lon3 << std::endl;
}

>>From Helsinki it is 1914.57km to Paris, bearing: -121.079
>>From Helsinki, 1000km to Paris takes us to Våbensted: 54.7882,11.5655

